# Having Trouble with Random Numbers in Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to generate random background colors to display to a user when they press a button on the screen. I have an immutable array of UIColor items and I have made a mutable copy to manipulate. When a random color is generated, that color is then returned and removed from the mutable copy of the array to prevent consecutive showings of the same color until all colors have been shown. This is supposed to happen until the array's count is 0, and then it recreates the array to repeat the process. However, when I get down to the array having between 2 and 0 items, the loop seems to turn into an infinite loop. What logic am I missing in my code (playground file)?

```
var currentColorIndexNumber = 0
var newColorIndexNumber = 0

let colorsArray = [
    UIColor(red: 90/255.0, green: 187/255.0, blue: 181/255.0, alpha: 1.0), //teal color
    UIColor(red: 222/255.0, green: 171/255.0, blue: 66/255.0, alpha: 1.0), //yellow color
    UIColor(red: 223/255.0, green: 86/255.0, blue: 94/255.0, alpha: 1.0), //red color
    UIColor(red: 239/255.0, green: 130/255.0, blue: 100/255.0, alpha: 1.0), //orange color
    UIColor(red: 77/255.0, green: 75/255.0, blue: 82/255.0, alpha: 1.0), //dark color
    UIColor(red: 105/255.0, green: 94/255.0, blue: 133/255.0, alpha: 1.0), //purple color
    UIColor(red: 85/255.0, green: 176/255.0, blue: 112/255.0, alpha: 1.0), //green color
]

var mutableColorsArray: [AnyObject] = colorsArray

func randomNumber() -> Int {
    // avoid repeating random integers
    while currentColorIndexNumber == newColorIndexNumber {
        var unsignedArrayCount = UInt32(mutableColorsArray.count)
        var unsignedRandomNumber = arc4random_uniform(unsignedArrayCount)
        newColorIndexNumber = Int(unsignedRandomNumber)
    }
    currentColorIndexNumber = newColorIndexNumber
    return newColorIndexNumber
}

func randomColor() -> UIColor {
    var randomIndex = randomNumber()
    var randomColor = mutableColorsArray[randomIndex] as UIColor
    mutableColorsArray.removeAtIndex(randomIndex)
    if mutableColorsArray.count == 0 {
        mutableColorsArray = colorsArray
    }
    return randomColor
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try shuffling instead.  Something along these lines:

```
var colorsArray = ["red","green","blue","yellow","purple"]
var currentColorIndexNumber = colorsArray.count

func shuffle<T>(inout array: Array<T>) -> Void {
  for index in 0..<colorsArray.count {
    let swapLocation = index + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(colorsArray.count - index)))
    if index != swapLocation {
      swap(&array[swapLocation], &array[index])
    }
  }
}

func randomColor() -> String {
  // shuffle first time through, then every time the list is exhausted
  if currentColorIndexNumber >= colorsArray.count - 1 {
    // shuffle, but guarantee first color after shuffling
    // is not the same as last color from previous round
    do {
      shuffle(&colorsArray)
    } while colorsArray[0] == lastColor
    currentColorIndexNumber = -1
    lastColor = colorsArray[colorsArray.count-1]
  }
  currentColorIndexNumber += 1
  return colorsArray[currentColorIndexNumber]
}

for i in (5*colorsArray.count) {
  print("\(randomColor()) ")
  if i % colorsArray.count == 0 {
    println()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had good results with

```
func randomObject(array: [AnyObject]) -> AnyObject {
    return array[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))]
}
```

To enumerate **all** of the elements in random order, just use a shuffle function as the one below, use the elements of the shuffled array in order and re-shuffle the array once it is exhausted.

```
func shuffleArray<T>(array: Array<T>) -> Array<T>  {
  for var i = array.count - 1; i > 0; i--  {
    var j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(i-1)))
    swap(&array[i], &array[j])
  }
  return array
}
```

Comment: This won't enumerate all colors without repeating, which I read as bnkohrn's intent.

Comment: True, I overlooked this requirement.